# How to nicely expand a Gauss Hypergeometric function?

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

Does anybody know how to obtain the z->1 expansion for the Gauss Hypergeometric 2F1(a,b;c;z) on Mathematica as shown [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/06/01/04/01/01/0002/) ? I tried to use Series with the assumption c-a-b non-integer, but the result is given in terms of Floor, Ceiling... I would like to have a result in terms of the Gamma functions, if possible, or other nice functions. I tried following the answer with FunctionExpand and the one with Inactive[Sum] given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202099/explicit-series-notation-for-hypergeometric-functions?r=SearchResults)
, but with no success.

Cheers

Comment: Try: `Series[Hypergeometric2F1[a, b, c, z], {z, 1, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> {z == 1, -a - b + c > 0}]`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk The assumption `z==1` seems to be unnecessary for an expansion near `z~1` I think.